# Creating a Console like UI in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, c#-4.0, user-interface

Hi I'm trying to create a console like interface using a richtextbox in WinForms using C#.

The reason why I am using a richtextbox is I want a few features such as selection,copy-paste that are not present in a normal console application.

I was wondering if it was possible to change the blinking cursor from the blinking "|" to a blinking "_"

Even if I could hide the original "|", I could then implement a functionality on the onchange event of the richtextbox to display the blinking, "_"

I also had another related question, but I don't know if I should put that here as well.

Also, if it will be easier to implement something like this using WPF, I'm willing to move.

Comment: look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application

Comment: Although I can't exactly use that, but thanks for the link. Gave me a few new ideas! :)

Comment: I think you can create your own cursor with extension `.cursor` and assign it in properties of richTextBox..

Comment: Selection and copy-paste not available in a normal console application? They are, just not with the normal keyboard shortcuts or right-click menu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your RichTextBox's caret. Take a look at this: [Custom Caret for WinForms richtextbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/63019/Custom-Caret-for-WinForms-richtextbox)

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this [Command Prompt Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14908/Command-Prompt-Control)

Answer (score 1):

May be this one will suite for your need

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor